# Create new column with reverse order using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column X containing the reverse order value of x shown below.

```
 x      X
aa01   01aa
bb02   02bb
cc03   03cc
```

I did slice and concatenate them manually and it worked anyway, but I am looking for a "smarter" way doing this.

```
df["X1"] = df["x"].str.slice(0,2)
df["X2"] = df["x"].str.slice(2,4)
df['X'] = df["X2"]+ df["X1"].map(str)
```

Comment: Why not a apply? `df.x.apply(lambda x: x[2:] + x[:2])`

Comment: this works too, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faster way would be using list comprehension instead of pandas str functions:

```
df['X'] = [s[-2:]+s[:2] for s in df.x]
```